# completion data doesn't append global array after extract from JSON (swift 4)

Tags: json, swift

I have an issue with saving struct into Array of struct after fetched from API. After I finish fetching the JSON data and using completion, the data cannot be appended into array inside completion block. I've been looking around for couple days, tried many things, and still doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

struct IndodaxApi:Decodable{
    var ticker:dataStruct
}

struct dataStruct: Decodable {
    var high:String
    var low:String
    var last:String
    var vol_idr:String
    var vol_btc:String

    init(high:String, low:String, last:String, vol_idr:String, vol_btc:String) {
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
        self.vol_idr = vol_idr
        self.vol_btc = vol_btc
        self.last = last
    }

    func printInfo() -> Void {
        print("High:\(high)")
        print("Low:\(low)")
        print("Last:\(last)")
        print("vol_idr:\(vol_idr)")
        print("vol_btc:\(vol_btc)")
    }
}

class data {
    private let link:String
    private let ticker:String
    private let coinlist_idr:[String]
    private var dataCoin:[dataStruct]

    init() {
        link = "https://indodax.com/api/"
        ticker = "/ticker"
        coinlist_idr = ["btc_idr"]
        dataCoin = [dataStruct]()
    }

    public func getData() -> [dataStruct] {
        dataCoin.removeAll()
        load()
        return dataCoin
    }
```

This function here means to append data returned from completionhandler into dataCoin array which is struct of DataStruct:

```
private func load(){
    var index = 0
    let totalCoin = coinlist_idr.count
    while(index<totalCoin){
        fetchcoin(coinName: getNextCoin(index), completionHandler: { (data) in
            self.dataCoin.append(data)
        })
        index+=1
    }
}
```

This function here is to fetch the data from API and pass into completionhandler:

```
public func fetchcoin(coinName:String, completionHandler: @escaping ((dataStruct)->Void)){
    let urlLink = self.link + coinName + self.ticker;
    let url = URL(string: urlLink)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let api = try JSONDecoder().decode(IndodaxApi.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let returnData = dataStruct(high: api.ticker.high, low: api.ticker.low, last: api.ticker.last, vol_idr: api.ticker.vol_idr, vol_btc: api.ticker.vol_btc)
                completionHandler(returnData)
            }
        }catch let jsonERR{
            print(jsonERR)
        }
    }.resume()
}

private func getNextCoin(_ coinName:Int)->String{
    return coinlist_idr[coinName]
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but why do you create a new `dataStruct` instance in the completion handler rather than using the decoded one? By the way please name structs with a starting capital letter. And `dataTask` works asynchronously. The method `getData()` cannot work.

Comment: @vadian i tried return the api directly , didnt work as well. Thats why i try create a new struct and test it. Noted for the struct with starting capital letter

Comment: The while loop is pointless. You have to use `DispatchGroup` to get notified  when the last data task has finished. And you have to add completion blocks to all methods which are related to asynchronous data processing.

Comment: @vadian noted, but how the completion block doesnt append the array? I tried one data only. I'll add DispatchGroup later.

Comment: It does append but much much later than the line `return dataCoin` is executed.

Comment: @vadian i tried print the length of array inside load() after loop , but didnt append, shown 0

Comment: After the loop it's useless. Once again, the completion handler is called much later. Please learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works.